# Mongodb insert not working with C# , try/catch shows no errors

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have C# app and I added the nugget mongodb driver.

My mongodb database is called  `DevServers`
My collection is called  `server`

So I'm trying to connect and then just insert a random document since I assume that is allowed with mongo , it doesn't match the other 3 in the collection/db

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://root:mypassword@10.100.40.204:27017"; 
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

          var db = client.GetDatabase("DevServers");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("server");


            var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"Brand","Dell"},
                {"Price","400"},
                {"Ram","8GB"},
                {"HardDisk","1TB"},
                {"Screen","16inch"}
            };


            collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

I refresh the Studio 3T app and it does not show any inserts.  No error in the try/catch,   what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the Async method without await. Your method has to be marked as async as well.

```
public async Task Save() {
   // rest of code here
   await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

Comment: Is the connection string info the same as what you're using in the Studio app? Is the mongod process still running?